# Automated scheduling based on availability

Tags: algorithm, sorting, querying, hungarian-algorithm, assignment-problem

**The data:**
Students which have varying availability at certain timestamps (hourly) throughout the week.

**The challenge:**
Creating a schedule based on the data above, where a single faculty member can meet with each student once that week, without any overlap between students.

**What I have tried so far**

- Creating a filter that checks which students have the least availability and prioritizing them
- Distributing based on days where more/fewer students are available

However, none of my attempts even came close to what I need, and I struggle to understand the mathematics of it all. How can I best create such a scheduling tool above?

Comment: Can you share your `attempts` and some sample in/outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Create a bipartite graph with one vertex per student and one vertex per timestamp. A student is connected to a timestamp by an edge if and only if this student is available at that timestamp.

Then search for a maximum matching in this bipartite graph. This is also called the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), and can be solved for instance with the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Note that this makes the assumption that timestamps are discrete. This might not correspond to the reality. But it's still a good place to start.